# Mpirun hangs when mpi send and recieve is put in a loop

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing, powerpc

I was trying to run the given program on a 4 node cluster using mpirun.

Node0 is distributing the data to node 1, 2 and 3.
In the program, computation has to be done for different values of variable 'dir',
ranging from -90 to 90.

So Node0 is distributing the data and collecting the result in a looped fashion(for different values of var 'dir').
When the `do {*******}while(dir<=90);` loop is given, mpirun hangs, and gets no output.
But when I comment the `do {*******}while(dir<=90);` loop output is obtained for initialized value of the variable `dir`,(`dir=-90`), and that output is correct. The problem occurs when given in loop.

Could anyone please help me solve this issue.

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    float dir=-90;
    int rank,numprocs;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    if(rank==0)
{
       do{

     /*initializing data*/
    for(dest=1;dest<numprocs;dest++)
    {

                  MPI_Send(&offset,1,MPI_INT,dest,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);              

    MPI_Send(&s_psi[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,dest,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    for (dest=1; dest<numprocs; dest++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_INT,dest,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);            
            MPI_Recv(&P[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,dest,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }

    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    timersub(&end,&start,&total);
    printf("time consumed=%ds %dus\n",total.tv_sec,total.tv_usec);
    dir++;
    }while(dir<=90);
    }


    if(rank>0)
{   
    MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);           

    MPI_Recv(&s_psi[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

    //Does the computation      
    }
    MPI_Send(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(&P[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}   
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The part where `rank > 0` should be enclosed in a loop.
Each MPI_Send should have its corresponding MPI_Recv.

```
if(rank>0) {   
     do {
         MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);           
         MPI_Recv(&s_psi[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         // Computation      
         MPI_Send(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&P[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         dir++;
    } while(dir <= 90);
}
```

But you probably don't know `dir` in you worker nodes. Usually, we node0 send a magic packet to end the workers.

at the end of node0 :

```
for(r = 1; r < numprocs; r++)
    MPI_Send(&dummy, 1, MPI_INT, r, STOP, COMM);
```

for the woker nodes :

```
if(rank>0) {   
     while(true) {
         MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);           
         MPI_Recv(&s_psi[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         // Computation      
         MPI_Send(&offset,1,MPI_INT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&P[offset],count,MPI_FLOAT,0,FROM_WORKER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

         if(MPI_Iprobe(ANY_SOURCE, STOP, COMM, &flag, &status)) {
             MPI_Recv(&dummy, 1, MPI_INT, ANY_SOURCE, STOP, COMM, NO_STATUS);
             break;
         }
    };
}
```

And you can finally `MPI_finalize`

By the way, you might want to look at blocking and not bloking Send/Recv.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have to run this application in a 4 node single core PowerPC cluster. Adding a 'do.. while'loop in the worker nodes solved the problem, when the application was run on pc. But mpirun still hangs while running on the PowerPC based cluster. The code was executed on the cluster using the command "mpirun --prefix /usr/local --hostfile /usr/local/etc/openmpi-default-hostfile -np 4 pgm" . What could be the reason for that ?

Comment: I edited my answer, which had a small issue (I forgot to increment `dir`). Anyway, since it worked on you pc, I assume you corrected it. About the problem on the powerpc-based cluster, I don't know. You probably should add `printf("[%d] %d\n", rank, dir)` in each loop to see where it hangs, and what Send has not its corresponding Recv.